# Confusing explanation of limiting the type parameter of a generic binary search tree in Java

Tags: java, generics, tree, binary-search-tree, comparable

I'm new to generics (and Java, and Stack Overflow), and there is a point in the textbook I'm learning from where it discusses the implementation of a generic binary search tree (excerpt below).

> The Comparable interface is generic, so let’s consider storing the following
>   type of elements in our search tree:
>
> < T extends Comparable< T>>
>
> This still causes a problem. Suppose that both Dog and Cat are subclasses of a
>   class Mammal and that the Mammal class implements the Comparable interface.
>   Now if we create a binary search tree that stores Mammal objects, then a
>   Dog and Cat could be added, but are not really comparable to each other. So this
>   solution, if used in this particular way, has the same problem as using the nongeneric
>   version of Comparable.
>   A more comprehensive solution, though not as intellectually satisfying, is to
>   write the generic type as:
>
> < T extends Comparable< ? super T>>
>
> This declaration restricts the comparable nature of the element to any superclass
>   of T.

So I get why the type parameter needs to be `Comparable< T>`, but then the book claims that this can pose problems if the tree of `Mammal`s contains different subtypes that attempt to invoke the `compareTo()` method on each other. Well if the reference type for the `Cat` and `Dog` objects in the tree is `Mammal`, then wouldn't they be invoking `Mammal`'s `compareTo()` method anyway (being `Comparable< Mammal>`), making it a valid comparison (just on the `Mammal` level)?

I don't understand what difference `Comparable< ? super T>` makes, because would that not be the same thing, except perhaps if `Mammal`s aren't `Comparable` then it falls back to a `Comparable` superclass like the `Animal` class or something?

I'm probably missing something, like some nasty consquence of type erasure or something that will cause the comparisons to not work like I'm thinking they would.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so you understand that `<T extends Comparable<T>>` works with a class like this:

```
class Mammal extends Comparable<Mammal>
```

Now you have a subclass of `Mammal`, `Cat`: `class Cat extends Mammal`. Due to inheritance `Cat` also implements `Comparable<Mammal>`, and, as you said, it can compare to all mammals (including cats, of course) due to the `compareTo(Mammal)` method that it inherited from `Mammal`.

But now the problem is that `Cat` does not work with the bound `<T extends Comparable<T>>`, because `Cat` does not implement `Comparable<Cat>`. You cannot solve this by having `Cat` implement `Comparable<Cat>`, because you can only implement an interface with one type parameter.

But conceptually, there is no problem with sorting a list of `Cat`, since `Cat`s can compare to other `Cat`s (they can compare to all mammals, which is more general; but the point is that they can compare to cats). So the problem is that our bound is too restrictive.

`<T extends Comparable<? super T>>` solves this problem, and allows `Cat` to be used. Recall the PECS rule -- Producer `extends` Consumer `super`. Well, the Comparable is a consumer and not a producer, because you pass an argument of type T into its `compareTo` method (consume), but no methods needs to return type T (produce). Hence, a `super` wildcard is appropriate.

Comment: Okay, after an hour or so of pondering and wonderful responses to my question I think I've got this. For < T extends Comparable< T>, a BST of Mammals will work just fine if it is full of Cats and Dogs (which are Comparable< Mammal> via inheritance). But if you want a BST of Cats, then this won't work because the Cats are only Comparable on the Mammal level. Therefore if we restrict the type argument for a BST to be < T extends Comparable< ? super T>, then we can have  BST of Mammals like before, but we can ALSO have a BST of Cats, because the Cats will then be compared on the superclass level.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, rewriting this to make i more clear

Consider the interface

```
< T extends Comparable<T> >
```

and then consider your subclass Cat

```
Cat extends Comparable<Cat>
```

This breaks a lot of the things in the binary search tree if there are other classes like Dog, because Comparable needs two of the same type. Cat should look like this then

```
Cat extends Comparable<Animal>
```

The author changes this to

```
< T extends Comparable<? super T> >
```

so that now we can add objects like

```
Cat extends Comparable<Animal>
```

because the parameter going into Comparable must be a superclass instead of the class itself. So it can be a Mammal -> Animal -> Object, but not, say a String

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm struggling to find the context to which your answer is applying. I was talking purely about the binary search tree's type parameter < T extends Comparable(something)> and it seems here you're talking about the Cat's implementing of the Comparable interface? Your answer is a little too concise and I'm new to generics so to me, it sounds like you're talking about something different :\

Comment: sorry, what i wrote was confusing, see if htis version makes sense

Answer (score 0):

**The main point is this.**
The class which you are choosing, should either implement a Comparable interface with the parameter as **It Self** or it can be any other super class which takes in class **the Base class** as the comparable parameter.